# PHPMailer no recoge datos input ni option

Tags: html, email, phpmailer

Recientemente he conseguido que desde una página con dominio se envíe un e-mail al completar el formulario. Me envía el e-mail con los campos rellenados menos dos de ellos, que vienen a ser el prefijo y el número de teléfono.

Cabe añadir que tengo un script para que dependiendo de `option` seleccionado me salga un `input` u otro y me cambie a `required` cuando sea mostrado en pantalla.

No sé por qué razón no lo coge en el e-mail que envía.

Os agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

(os dejo todo el código y fotos a mayores para que podáis ver cómo lo tengo puesto)

**En el código html**

```
<form action="./php/data-email.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="info-form">
            <span style="font-size: 25px; color: #1F78B8; width:50%; height:50%; text-transform: uppercase;">
                <div data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="3000"><i class="fas fa-info" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Sol·licita Informació</div>
            </span>

                <div class="form-group form-group1">
                    <div class="name-group" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="2500">
                        <label class="animated-label title-form" for="Nom Empresa"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> Nom de l'Empresa*</label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control1" type="text" name="nom-empresa" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-group" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="2500">
                        <label class="animated-label title-form" for="nom"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i> Nom*</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nom-persona" required>
                    </div>


                </div><br><br>

                <div class="form-group" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="2000">
                    <label class="animated-label title-form" for="email" ><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> E-mail*</label>
                    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" required/>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group1" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="1500">
                    <label class="animated-label title-form" for="phone"><i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i> Teléfon de Contacte *</label><br>
                      <select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" class="form-control-option title-form" required onchange="showInp()" style="width: 90px; height: 33px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                        <option value="" class="title-form">--Prefix</option>
                        <option name="prefix" value="and" class="title-form">+376</option>
                        <option name="prefix" value="esp" class="title-form">+34</option>
                        <option name="prefix" value="fr" class="title-form">+33</option>

                    </select>

                      <input name="phone" id="andphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[8|7|3|6]\d{5}$"/>
                    <input name="phone" id="espphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[9|8|7|6]\d{8}$"/>
                    <input name="phone" id="frphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text"  pattern="^[1|2|3|4|5|6]\d{9}$"/>
                </div><br><br>

                <div class="form-group" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
                    <label class="animated-label title-form message-queries" name="message" for="message" ><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Missatge *</label>
                    <textarea id="message" class="form-control" name="message" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 150px; min-height: 150px; max-height: 100%; resize: none; font-family: 'Montserrat', Sans-Serif;"></textarea>

                </div>

            <div style="text-align: center;" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="500">
                <button name="submit" value="send" class="send-button">
                ENVIAR
                </button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

**La parte que no me recoge es esta:**

```
<div class="form-group form-group1" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="1500">
                    <label class="animated-label title-form" for="phone"><i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i> Teléfon de Contacte *</label><br>
                      <select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" class="form-control-option title-form" required onchange="showInp()" style="width: 90px; height: 33px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                        <option value="" class="title-form">--Prefix</option>
                        <option name="prefix" value="and" class="title-form">+376</option>
                        <option name="prefix" value="esp" class="title-form">+34</option>
                        <option name="prefix" value="fr" class="title-form">+33</option>

                    </select>

                      <input name="phone" id="andphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[8|7|3|6]\d{5}$"/>
                    <input name="phone" id="espphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[9|8|7|6]\d{8}$"/>
                    <input name="phone" id="frphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text"  pattern="^[1|2|3|4|5|6]\d{9}$"/>
                </div>
```

**El código PHP es así:**

```php
<?php
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        set_time_limit(0);
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        $nameb = $_POST['nom-empresa'];
        $namep = $_POST['nom-persona'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $to = "ejemplo@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Contacto - Página Web";
        $body = '<html>
                <body style="text-align: center;">
                    <h2>Formulario de contacto - via ejemplo.com</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <h3>Nombre de la empresa:</h3>
                    <p>'.$nameb.'</p>
                    <br>
                    <h3>Nombre de la persona solicitante:</h3>
                    <p>'.$namep.'</p>
                    <br>
                    <h3>E-mail</h3>
                    <p>'.$email.'</p>
                    <br>
                    <h3>teléfono</h3>
                    <p>'.$prefix.' - '.$phone.'</p>
                    <h3>Mensaje</h3>
                    <p>"'.$message.'"</p>';



        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; //Mensajes de debug; 0 = no mostrar (en producción), 1 = de cliente, 2 = de cliente y servidor
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host ='smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true)
            );
        $mail->Username = 'ejemplo@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '12345678';

            //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('ejemplo@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo($email);

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'E-mail de '.$nameb.' - via ejemplo.com';
        $mail->Body = $body;



    if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Error al enviar: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "Mensaje enviado correctamente";
    }}

    ?>
```

Y siguiendo el proceso de rellenar el formulario obtengo esto:

[image: Formulario rellenado]

[image: Código que devuelve la operación "enviar" cliente/servidor]

[image: E-mail recibido finalmente]

Comment: te lo coje si envias un prefijo y un telefono con las opciones de frances? me da que te esta sobreescribiendo el ultimo parametro con los anteriores,  porque tienen el mismo nombre, y al dejarlos en blanco, te llegan vacio. Recuerda que lo que se envia en un formulario es el `nombre` del campo, no su `id`

Comment: Además el prefijo lo debes de coger del select, cuyo name es "telprefix"

Comment: Pues sí, me coge el teléfono en la última opción fr. Pero lo que sigue sin cogerme es el prefijo, aunque miraré de cambiarlo a {telprefix}.

Comment: Al cambiar el `$_POST['telprefix']` me ha enviado correctamente el value del option, pero siempre envía el último `input`. Debería añadirlos con names distintos cada uno?

Comment: He cambiado los `input name=""` y en el código `php` le he añadido cada uno de ellos en el `body` y ahora me envía todos los campos correctamente. Muchísimas gracias por darme el empujón que necesitaba @Jakala y @Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia

Answer (score 1):

El error está tanto en el archivo php como en el html. Me ha funcionado correctamente añadir a los input un name distinto para cada uno y en el php añadir cada uno de ellos:

**HTML**

```html
<input name="phonead" id="andphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[8|7|3|6]\d{5}$"/>
<input name="phonees" id="espphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[9|8|7|6]\d{8}$"/>
<input name="phonefr" id="frphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text"  pattern="^[1|2|3|4|5|6]\d{9}$"/>
```

Y entonces en el `php` añadirlos así y cambiar la mención del `name` para que sea del `select` y no del los `option`.

**PHP**

```php
[...]

$prefix = $_POST['telprefix'];
$phonead = $_POST['phonead'];
$phonees = $_POST['phonees'];
$phonefr = $_POST['phonefr'];

[...]
```